# How to absorb the pointer interaction by inner widget conditionally in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stack, where ("canvas") is a widget that fills the stack and all other widgets ("elements") are above it. I want when the user presses an element, to select it (using a BLoC event), and in this state, if he taps anywhere on the element or canvas I want to deselect it (also by BLoC event).

I tried putting a gesture detector wrapping the canvas and gesture detector wrapping the element at the same time, but when I tap the element both detectors are invoked so non-deterministic behaviour is happening.

How can I achieve what I want: in unselected state tapping an element will select it and tapping on canvas does nothing / in selected state tapping anywhere deselects ?

I mean is there an easier and shorter way than calculating the coordinates of a tap event and check if they are inside the element or outside it i.e. in the canvas?

Comment: `Scaffold(
body: Stack(
children: [
Positioned.fill(
child: GestureDetector(
onTap: () => print('deselect'),
child: CustomPaint(
painter: FooPainter(),
),
),
),
...[Alignment.topLeft, Alignment.topRight, Alignment.bottomLeft, Alignment.bottomRight].map((a) => Align(
alignment: a,
child: Container(
width: 100,
height: 100,
color: Colors.green,
child: GestureDetector(onTap: () => print('select'))
),
),
),
],
),
),`

Comment: @psking this is exactly what I said in the question that I tried and didn't work (although I am not using `CustomPaint`, I just called my outer widget "canvas" for sake of example). In this case you mentioned the inner and outer gesture detectors are both invoked, how can I prevent the outer from being invoked from the inner GD based on some condition? Is there a widget for this or should I define a boolean for this reason and track its value?

Comment: *"In this case you mentioned the inner and outer gesture detectors are both invoked,"* - no, only one `GestureDetector` is invoked - just try the code i posted

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [IgnorePointer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IgnorePointer-class.html) widget when no element is selected, that way only the element `GestureDetector` is fired.